# How do I change the font style of text displayed on hover with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I feel like this should be an easy one but nothing I'm doing seems to be working. I may be targeting the element wrong or may be inputting the wrong CSS - I'm fairly new to the coding side of things so any help would be appreciated.

This is for a Wordpress site (page in question is [here](https://southernpictures.com.au/productions/))

For the CSS component I have tried the following

```
.project.small.effect-1 .details.has-skills .text {
font-family: 'Oswald'}
```

and

```
.project.small .title {
font-family: 'Oswald'}
```

I've also tried adding !important to override any stylings set by the WP theme but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick either.

Is there something that I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS:hover Selector. See the snippet below:

```css
p{
  font-family: Arial;
}

p:hover{
  font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<p>The text that will be modified.</p>
```

More on `:hover` selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Comment: Not was I was looking for. I can't update the HTML tags due to the limitations of the site builder so have to work with the set identifiers. I worked out that I was, as assumed targeting the wrong element and fixed the code and it is now working with `.page-id-37 .site-main h3 {
font-family: 'oswald';}`.